# how to toggle 'Include Docs' more easily inside the cloudant dashboard?

Tags: cloudant

At the moment it takes a few clicks to toggle the 'include_docs' flag inside the cloudant dashboard.  If you do this a lot, it can be a little time consuming.

How can I speed this process up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a javascript [bookmarklet](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154):

```
javascript:(function(){
   if(document.location.toString().contains('include_docs=true')){
      document.location=document.location.toString().replace('include_docs=true', '')
   } else {
      if (document.location.toString.contains('?') {
          document.location+='&include_docs=true'
      } else {
          document.location+='?include_docs=true'
      }
   }
}())
```

When I want to toggle the 'include_docs' on or off, I can simply click on this bookmark in my bookmark toolbar.

Note: I have only tested this on firefox.